# как обратиться к элементу, обьявленому в коде разметки из функции?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как обратиться к элементу(анимировать его свойства)в коде функции?
например,в коде разметки обьявлен прямоугольник с именем newRectangle:

```
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Name="newRectangle" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Blue"></Rectangle>
```

пытался сделать так

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(myInt32Animation,"newRectangle");
```

,но получаю InvalidOperationException:

Не существует применимой области имен для разрешения имени "newRectangle".
Что следует добавить для нормальной работы кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы делаете анимацию из code-behind, лучше делайте так:

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(myInt32Animation, newRectangle);
```

Это будет работать независимо от пространства имён в XAML.

---

Не забыли ли вы сказать ещё `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty`?

Comment: вызов Storyboard.SetTargetProperty() есть в коде    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myInt32Animation,
                new PropertyPath(Rectangle.WidthProperty));

Comment: Отлично. А `SetTarget` работает?

Comment: ,да,SetTarget решил проблему .Спасибо за помощь!!

Comment: @david_I: Пожалуйста!